# Memory efficient and fastest way to create batchs and applying fuction to python list

Tags: python, list, generator, iterable

**I need to create batch of 5 and apply function on each value of the list in memory efficient and 
fastest way. I need to avoid two steps to do the batching. I need to do it in a single step in most efficient and fatest way. Please help in doing it in a efficient way.**

**Sample code:**

```
import json
from uuid import uuid4

rows = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15]

rowlist = [r*r for r in rows]

records = [{'Data': json.dumps(rowlist[i:i + 5]), 'PartitionKey': str(uuid4())} for i in range(0, len(rowlist), 5)]

print(records)
```

**Results:**

```
[{'Data': '[1, 4, 9, 16, 25]', 'PartitionKey': '73ba1cba-248c-4b26-982e-1d902627bfe6'}, {'Data': '[36, 49, 64, 81, 100]', 'PartitionKey': '02a986bf-0495-4620-a3d4-0f0b91cd24d6'}, {'Data': '[121, 144, 169, 196, 225]', 'PartitionKey': 'a0ef674e-95f3-4cb0-8e0b-ad052f7726bf'}]
```

Comment: So... what do you mean by _most efficient and fastest way_? What are you trying to achieve? What makes it slow? How do you want us to optimise it further?

Comment: The batching is taking more time as per the size of the list(Batching should be faster), creating batches should be faster and I'm getting out of memory issues, due to size of the list I'm parsing. I want to avoid that issue as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're having memory issues, you can try to maintain everything as an iterator until the last possible moment. Then you can iterate over each item one at a time, or call `list(records)` if you want to try to make a final list:

(I removed the json and uuid to make the structure clearer):

```
rows = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15]

sqr = lambda r: r*r

records = ({'Data': group} for group in zip(*[map(sqr,rows)] * 5))

for record in records:
    print(record)
```

Prints:

```
{'Data': (1, 4, 9, 16, 25)}
{'Data': (36, 49, 64, 81, 100)}
{'Data': (121, 144, 169, 196, 225)}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Is there a way to batch based on size. I have to make  batchs of size 1 MB ( I have a limitation of size I can write at a time)

Comment: @basic I'm not sure the best way to calculate how large the objects will be. However, if you figure that out you can use `itertools.islice` to iterate though the generator a chunk at a time.